# What do you call a sudden movement of the neck and head that you do when you think about something stupid or do something stupid?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for that, but sometimes you may imagine yourself doing something stupid and then twist and shake your head for a brief second, what is that movement called? Is there even a word for it? It doesn't have to be the neck and the head only, because I am not sure how other people "physically" react.

Comment: Is there a local word in your native language.  It seems that this might refer to a gesture that is local to one part of the world.

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for, but the term "double-take" seems related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Head Motion

A slight, quick, repeated motion is a ***jitter***. Larger repeated movements are a ***shake*** or ***wag***. Shaking and wagging are slower: shaking the head is a rotation at the neck, and wagging is a shoulder-to-shoulder lateral movement of the head.

> She jittered her head in disbelief.
>
> Astounded, I wagged my head.

All of these apply to movements of any body part, not just the head.

Referring to the ***head swimming*** usually refers to a feeling of lightheadedness from dizziness or intoxication but could describe certain back-and-forth motions of the head.

> My head swam for a moment to show them I realized how dopey I must have sounded saying that.

Another that applies to the head — the mind, really — and may be the best fit is the idiom ***shake the cobwebs loose***. Having recently woken up, fatigued at the end of the day, or preoccupation with other matters may slow one’s mental faculties.

> ‘What a stupid thing to say,’ I thought and rattled my head to shake the cobwebs loose.
>
> I need a moment here to shake the cobwebs loose.

### Whole-Body Motion

Depending on the level of surprise or shock, more than just the head may be involved. [Owain's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/205349/32416) includes ***start*** and ***jerk***. These are single, unrepeated movements. A related single movement is ***startle*** used as a verb.

> He startled, unable to believe what he had just witnessed.

When hit with utter shock or surprise, all or part of the body may be ***taken aback***: rolling the head backward (perhaps with raised eyebrows), bending backward at the neck and waist, or even taking a step backward. Similar expressions are ***blown away*** and ***took my/his/her breath away***. All of these are used figuratively to express extreme surprises, but taking the breath away can have the connotation of romance and falling in love.

> Billy was taken aback by what she revealed.
>
> I am just blown away with disappointment.

### Emphasizing the Effect

Disappointment in oneself or others, surprise, and so on may provoke movement of the head or other physical responses, and we do it because we are ***boggled*** or to ***regain composure***.

> His mind boggled, he slowly shook his head in an effort to regain his composure.

Answer (score 0):

to start

> intransitive verb
>
> 1a : to move suddenly and violently : spring started angrily to his feet
>   b : to react with a sudden brief involuntary movement : started when a shot rang out

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/start

to jerk

> 2 : a single quick motion of short duration
>   4a : an involuntary spasmodic muscular movement ...

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerk